# Temporarily Facading asmx Web Service With WCF Service

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, refactoring

I have an application that is an asmx web service written in .NET 2.0 with some business logic and a repository sitting underneath it.

The plan is that this web service will serve as the API for applications that want the data that it saves and retrieves.

Longer term, I know that the web service is likely to be replaced by a WCF service when the .NET 2.0 code base is refactored and becomes a .NET 4 codebase.

In order to reduce the impact on consumers of the API, I am considering whether it is a good idea to drop a WCF service as a facade over the asmx service. This will remain in place while the .NET 2.0 code is refactored. When there is no .NET 2.0 code left, the asmx service will disappear and the WCF service will talk to the business logic without an asmx service in the way.

My questions are

What kind of performance overhead will this cause?

Is there a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read your question as “can I reference a .Net 2.0 component from a .Net 4 WCF service"

This link
[confirms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx)

The .NET Framework 4 is backward-compatible with applications that were built with the .NET Framework versions 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5. In other words, applications and components built with previous versions of the .NET Framework will work on the .NET Framework 4.

Comment: Excellent - so I can skip writing a web service altogether and write a WCF service that consumes the .NET 2 components. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You'll pay a double serialization / deserialization penalty for the additional service layer.  If your messages are small, this won't be as noticeable.

You might want to deploy a WCF version of the same service using BasicHttpBinding.  That way you get the best of both worlds:

- The service is being deployed in one place using WCF (and is still available to legacy clients)
- You can expose additional endpoints using different bindings if you want for the newer code.

**EDIT:** Of course, you could just hook up your new code to the old code using WCF based proxies.  As long as you keep things named the same, your later refactor of the service shouldn't be too painful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I would be very happy to implement a WCF service without the web service underneath it if it is possible for the WCF service to live with the .NET 2 code below it (for a while). Is that what you mean by using WCF Based Proxies? If so, can you expand on that as I'd rather not double the serialization cost.

Comment: Yeah, basically I'm saying one option is to leave the old services exactly as they are, but just create WCF clients for them.  In Visual Studio, you have two options - create the new WCF clients (aka Service Reference) or the old "Web Reference".  Theoretically, if you keep the sames of the webMethods and the classes the same, your code doesn't have to chance when you eventually rewrite the services in WCF.